# Is it possible to crack g++ rand()?

Tags: exploit, random, c++, gcc

So, I have this:

I know that *some code* was used to generate a random sequence, and it looked roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    std::string temp = "1234567890";
    srand(MAGICNUMBER);
    for (int i = 0;; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            temp[j] = alphabet[rand() % alphabet.size()];
        }
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It was used to generate a sequence of 124660967 strings, the last of which was "2lwd9JjVnE", and then stopped. The compilator used was 64-bit g++ 4.8 for Linux. What I want is to find the 124660968th string – that is, the one that would have been printed next. The caveat, of course, is that I don't know the `MAGICNUMBER`. I'm pretty sure that it's possible to brute-force all possibilities, but it would take millennia, it seems. I've tried to snoop around in `rand()` source code, but I don't really understand it, much less exploit it. Is it possible to find that string in more or less reasonable time?

**UPD** Is it even possible to generate what is supposed to go after my string *without* finding out the seed?

Comment: The compiler is (or *should be*) irrelevant in this case. The interesting part is the libc, because that's where rand() is implemented. And the seed is "only" an `unsigned int`...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well, the standard does _not_ provide any details on how random should be implemented, so the compiler seems to be quite relevant, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are confusing the compiler with the standard library. The compiler only cares about (in this case) C++ *keywords*, whereas the standard library builds on top of that to make it easier to implement useful functionality by providing things like `cout`, `rand()`, `std::string` and so on.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, ah, I see, okay; learned something new today, I guess

Comment: Related, except about C, not C++: [How to predict C rand()?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/31643/2138)

Comment: **Why** do you want to find the one that comes next?  Why can't you just generate a new random value?  Note that the method isn't completely secure anyways, since `rand()` doesn't return crypto-level results, and the mod afterwards will skew to one side (since the range of the random is not a multiple of the alphabet size).

Comment: Repost? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299865/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-next-item-in-random-sequence    

Anyway, `srand()` takes an unsigned integer, so why not just search the binary or memory for the number? Once you know the *MAGICNUMBER*, you can easily predict what comes next because it follows a set formula to generate random numbers. However, if you are wanting to reverse the PRNG without *MAGICNUMBER*, using only the known outputs, I suppose it is possible, but difficult. You would need to determine the internal state when the last random number was generated

Answer (score 7):

The compiler itself is irrelevant; the `rand()` function is [implemented in libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers.html).

The glibc implementation uses a linear congruential generator (LCG) or a linear feedback shift register (LFSR) for its `rand()`. These can be quite easily cracked given some of the outputs (which it seems you have). The details can be found in the answer to [another question already asked here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator?rq=1), but the crux is that LCGs and LFSRs are not secure and some simple maths and probability can gain you the right answer pretty quickly.

You'll need to work out which version of glibc was used, but the compiler version should give you a rough idea of the patch state of the system, so you can infer it from that.

You can find more resources on Google, but here's a quick set of links to help:

- [LCGs on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)
- [LFSRs on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)
- [Cracking PHP's rand()](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Argyros/BH_US_12_Argyros_PRNG_WP.pdf) [PDF] - relevant because it uses the glibc function for rand(), and this is covered in the paper.
- [Untwister](https://github.com/altf4/untwister) - PRNG seed recovery tool with support for rand()
- [Snowflake](https://github.com/GeorgeArgyros/Snowflake) - Another PRNG seed recovery tool

Comment: ...and this is why you should use a cryptographically secure RNG for any situation where people guessing the output is a problem. This doesn't just apply to cryptography, but also to online gaming and especially online gambling.

Comment: I suspect this is a challenge of sorts, which is why I didn't provide a "this is how you win" walkthrough answer. And also because that's a lot of effort. But regardless, you're right - LCG/LFSR designs simply aren't of the right quality for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Google says:

> In order to generate random-like numbers, `srand` is usually initialized to some distinctive runtime value, like the value returned by function `time` (declared in header `<ctime\>`). This is distinctive enough for most trivial randomization needs.

If this technique is used and you know a more or less close estimate of the time (like, if you can narrow it down to a day), a brute force attack on the left input space will probably be feasible.

Other than that, if you follow google some more you find a [series of blog entries](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html) that might lead you down the right track.

Comment: Nope, I know for granted that the seed was not time-related; so that won't work.

Secondly, as I understood, `rand()` can use Mersenne Twister, but by default it is "Linear feedback shift register" as google and source code tell me, so that blog post doesn't seem to help much as well

Comment: The other posts in that series handle the linear congruential PRNG.